# spark partition.toList fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What I want to is to group multiple elements in a partition and then do some operations on the grouped elements in each partition. But I found the conversion from partition to list failed. See the below example:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("a","b","c","d","e"), 2)
val mapped = rdd.mapPartitions( partition =>
   {
      val total = partition.size
          var first = partition.toList match
            {
             case Nil => "EMPTYLIST"
             case _ =>  partition.toList.head  
            }

  var finalResult = ArrayBuffer[String]()
  finalResult += "1:"+first;
  finalResult += "2:"+first;
  finalResult += "3:"+first;

  finalResult.iterator
})

mapped.collect()
```

Result:

> Array[String] = Array(1:EMPTYLIST, 2:EMPTYLIST, 3:EMPTYLIST,
>   1:EMPTYLIST, 2:EMPTYLIST, 3:EMPTYLIST)

why partition.toList is always empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*partition* is an iterator, the size count consumes it so at the point you are converting it to a List, it's already empty; To go through the partition more than once, you can convert the partition to a list at the beginning and then do what you need later on the List:

```
val mapped = rdd.mapPartitions( partition =>
    {
        val partitionList = partition.toList
        val total = partitionList.size
        val first = partitionList match
            {
              case Nil => "EMPTYLIST"
              case _ =>  partitionList.head  
            }

        var finalResult = ArrayBuffer[String]()
        finalResult += "1:"+first;
        finalResult += "2:"+first;
        finalResult += "3:"+first;

        finalResult.iterator
    })

mapped.collect
// res7: Array[String] = Array(1:a, 2:a, 3:a, 1:c, 2:c, 3:c)
```

Comment: Is partition.toList incorporating data from worker to driver?

Comment: I don't think so. It should still stay on each worker just converted to a list from an iterator. Also see some discussions [here](http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com/2015/11/mappartition-example.html).

Comment: Then it is interesting. If I run "partition.take(10)", does it get 10 elements from each worker?

Comment: It does. You can test it with this command `rdd.mapPartitions(p => p.take(2)).collect` which returns `Array(a, b, c, d)` for your sample data. And `rdd.mapPartitions(p => p.take(1)).collect` returns `Array(a, c)`.